# To split delimited value in column input in where clause

Tags: oracle

I need to split a column which is Pipe delimited and compare with records. Something like this

```
select 1 
  from T1 t1 
 where t1.date_col not between '01-JAN-2005' and '31-JAN-2005';
```

I need to fill the between clause value from reference table where the data is something like

```
ref_table
col_1
01-JAN-2005 | 31-JAN-2005
```

Query I am trying to achieve

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR ( col_1
           , '^[^|]+') from ref_table
```

Which is resulting into `01-JAN-2005`.

```
Table T1 
 date_col 
  01-Jan-05 
  15-Jan-05 
  31-Mar-05 

Ref_table 
 col_1 
 01-JAN-2005 | 31-JAN-2005
```

Comment: Can you show some data sample from your table (just a small sample of what you have) and from that sample what would be the desired result.

Comment: Table T1  T1
date_col
01-Jan-05
15-Jan-05
31-Mar-05
Ref_table
col_1
01-JAN-2005 | 31-JAN-2005, i need to exclude dates from T1 table where date_col not falling between 01-JAN-2005 and 31-JAN-2005 which is configured in ref_table as 01-FEB-2016 | 29-FEB-2016

Comment: So the desired output would be `31-Mar-05` is that it ?

Comment: One more thing wanted to ask you , sorry this is off the topic but similar to REGEXP_SUBSTR function , i need to to replace a string like 'This is Oracle      1@1' to This is Oracle, How thats possible. I need to consider till Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as this:

```
--Sample data
with t1 as (
  select '01-Jan-05' col_1 union 
  select '15-Jan-05' union 
  select '31-Mar-05'
),
Ref_table as (
  select '01-JAN-2005 | 31-JAN-2005' col_1
)
select *
  from t1, 
       Ref_table r
 where to_date(t1.col_1, 'DD/MON/YY')
          not between to_date(trim(regexp_replace(r.col_1, '(.*)\|.*', '\1')), 'DD/MON/YY')
                  and to_date(trim(regexp_replace(r.col_1, '.*\|(.*)', '\1')), 'DD/MON/YY')
```

Although you really should improve your `ref_table` design. Store values with some char separated always turns out to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Join the dates from table `t1` with the intervals from the reference table and subtract the result from the original set of dates:

```
  select t11.date_col
    from t1 t11
   minus
  select t12.date_col 
    from t1 t12
    join (
            select to_date ( trim ( substr(col_1, 1, instr(col_1, '|') - 1) ), 'DD-Mon-YYYY' )    d_from
                 , to_date ( trim ( substr(col_1, instr(col_1, '|') + 1) ), 'DD-Mon-YYYY' )       d_to
              from ref_table
         ) rt on (
                    rt.d_from <= t12.date_col
                AND rt.d_to   >= t12.date_col
              )
       ;
```

I assume that `col_1` from your reference table contains the excluded intervals in pairs.

Comment: Exactly you are correct , i shouldn't consider the dates falling between the col_1 of reference table which has range